# How to find the last occurence of whitespace in string that is not between digits or trailing whitespace

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

should not consider the white space at the end of the string or the white space in between two digits, but it can be either preceding or followed by a digit but not in between digits.
I wrote a regex expression ,but it is not working for all conditions according to my requirement.

```
Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("\\s(?![\\d\\s]*\\d$)");
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(input);
int lastIndex=-1;
while(matcher.find()){
lastIndex=matcher.start());
}
```

how can i achieve my requirement using regex expression and any other way to get last occurrence without while loop?
Example

```
jumnsch@domain.com m 5180-3807-3679-8221 612 3/1/2010
                    ^
hello this card number 4444 5555 6666 7777
                      ^
hello this bob
          ^
```

Comment: Please edit the question with more details instead of just answering in comments.

Comment: What's the goal? Another idea: [`^(.*\p{L}) +\b`](https://regex101.com/r/zMmICB/2) (*first group* holds beginning).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a look-ahead assertion:

Assert that the candidate space is followed by at least one non-white space character and any further white space (if any) is surrounded by digits or occurs at the end of the string.

For that "surrounding" condition you can again use look-around assertions. This regex will only match white space that is surrounded by digits or occurs at the end of the string with a preceding digit: `"(?<=\\d)\\s+(?!\\D)"`. Only that type of white space and `\\s*$` will be allowed **after** the potentially matched space with this assertion:

```
"(?=\\S+((?<=\\d)\\s+(?!\\D)\\S*)*\\s*$)"
```

Now we could add the requirement of the candidate space itself: that it should either have no digit before it, or no digit following it:

```
"(?:\\s(?=\\D)|(?<!\\d)\\s)(?=\\S+((?<=\\d)\\s+(?!\\D)\\S*)*\\s*$)"
```

Code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\s(?=\\D)|(?<!\\d)\\s)(?=\\S+((?<=\\d)\\s+(?!\\D)\\S*)*\\s*$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
int lastIndex=-1;
if (matcher.find()) { // We only expect at most one match
    lastIndex = matcher.start();
    // Do something with lastIndex
}
```

Comment: OP is not clear in his question, but from their comment it looks like digit is not required to be near space: just spaces surrounded  by two digits are not allowed.

Comment: I forgot to come back to you, @markalex, but I think you are right and I had updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this regex pattern: `(\s)(?:[-\d\s/]+|\w+)$`

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s)(?:[-\\d\\s/]+|\\w+)$");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
  int lastIndex = -1;
  if (matcher.find()) {
    lastIndex = matcher.start();
  }
```

See demo here: [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Dw1tVm/1) and [Java](https://onecompiler.com/java/3z5r488yf).

Comment: It is not really working https://regex101.com/r/OicZBo/2

Comment: Also, what `[\\d\\s]+|\\w+` supposed to mean? Why not just `[\\w\\s]+`?

Comment: @markalex it should be working according to examples that are in a comment, although the examples + description are still not too precise.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answers. in this string :"jumnsch@domain.com m 5555-6666-7777-8888 612 3/1/2010" i want to return the white space character before 5180.

Comment: @lewon chow there isn't even `5180` and you still keep adding not too precise examples scattered around comments instead of **editing the question as you should**.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to have the last occurrence, you can use `.*` and have the dot match a newline finding the last occurrence over all lines. Note that `\s` also matches a newline.

```
(?s)^.*(\s(?<!\d.)(?=\d)|\s(?<=\d.)(?!\d|\s*$)|\s(?<=[^\d\s].)(?=[^\d\s]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VwiosT/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/FeW1A8)

Then you can use `matcher.find()` and get the index from group 1 using `matcher.start(1)`

```
String regex = "(?s)^.*(\\s(?<!\\d.)(?=\\d)|\\s(?<=\\d.)(?!\\d|\\s*$)|\\s(?<=[^\\d\\s].)(?=[^\\d\\s]))";
String string = "jumnsch@domain.com m 5180-3807-3679-8221 612 3/1/2010\n\n"
        + "hello this card number 4444 5555 6666 7777\n\n"
        + "hello this bob";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("[" + matcher.group(1) + "]");
    System.out.println(matcher.start(1));
}
```

Output

```
[ ]
109
```

If you have single lines, you can use `\h` to match a horizontal whitespace character.

```
^.*(\h(?<!\d.)(?=\d)|\h(?<=\d.)(?!\d|\h*$)|\h(?<=[^\d\h].)(?=[^\d\h]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3BRR1b/1)

Answer (score 1):

If double spaces are not present:

```
((?<=\D) | (?=\D))(?!$|.*((?<=\D) | (?=\D)(?!$)))
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ukGgZpwG7B013u).

Comment: Thank you , can you add one more condition that space must not be trailing. Example : "jumnsch@domain.com m 5180-3807-3679-8221 612 3/1/2010 ". here it should return white space character after m.

Comment: @lemonchow added a negative look ahead `(?!$)` (which means "not followed by end of input") to ignore spaces at the end. Live demo updated too.